# Sudo comes up with an error, cannot run anything as root

Tags: command-line, lubuntu, sudo, root

For some reason, when I try to run any programs (I am trying to run a rootkit hunter: rkhunter) as root on the command line with sudo like this:

```
sudo rkhunter
```

Then I get this message:

```
You must be the root user to run this program
```

and then I get these lines:

```
sudo: error in /etc/sudo.conf, line 0 while loading plugin 'sudoers_policy'
sudo: /usr/lib/sudo/sudoers.so must only be writable by owner
sudo: fatal error, unable to load plugins
```

I try typing in just `sudo` but that comes up with the same three errors as above. Also in `/etc/` sudo.conf does not exist.

I cannot run any other programs as root through sudo. It was also strange because I could run as root a day ago.
I would like it to work.

Just so you know, I am the only user of this computer, and the administrator, running Lubuntu 14.04.1.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

If you can login as root:

```
$ su root     #enter password
$ chmod 644 /usr/lib/sudo/sudoers.so
$ chown -R root /usr/lib/sudo
```

**

- on ubuntu 22.04 the proper directory for sudoers.so is
  /usr/libexec/sudo/sudoers.so

**

If not, you'll have to startup in recovery mode, get write permission on your disk, and change the mode of that file. https://wiki.ubuntu.com/RecoveryMode

```
$ mount -o remount,rw /
$ chmod 644 /usr/lib/sudo/sudoers.so
```

**

```
on ubuntu 22.04 the proper directory for sudoers.so is /usr/libexec/sudo/sudoers.so
```

**

Comment: I'm using a headless raspberry pi - how would I start in recovery mode without a keyboard or monitor?

Comment: Doesn't it have a sdcard that you easily can adjust on your desktop/laptop?

Comment: It does have an sdcard, good thinking, I can just plug it in and boot from there

Comment: 2021, still works :)

Comment: You can also login as root on WSL using `wsl -u root` from PowerShell or CMD

Answer (score 4):

1st open your terminal then type and enter

```
pkexec su
```

it will log you in as a root user

now type (replace username with your PC's username):

`chown -R username /usr/lib/`

now open file explorer and goto `/usr` or type this in another terminal: `nautilus /usr`

now, right click on the lib folder and goto 'Permissions' tab.

From there change the access of 'Group' and 'Others' to- 'Access files'

now click on the button 'Change Permissions for Enclosed Files' 
now change the access of 'Group' and 'Others' to- 'Access files' or 'Read-only'.

now close that window and return to the terminal(the one with root user).

now type

```
chown -R root /usr/lib/
```

*voila!*

now you can use `sudo` again.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't login as root, then start Ubuntu in recovery mode, from the menu select "Drop to shell prompt", press Enter, and then type the following:

```
mount -o remount,rw /
mount --all
chmod 644 /usr/lib/sudo/sudoers.so
chown -R /usr/lib/sudo/
```

You should be able to run "sudo" commands now, including here, in recovery mode console, for example you can just run `sudo` to test if it was fixed.

**

```
on ubuntu 22.04 the proper directory for sudoers.so is /usr/libexec/sudo/sudoers.so
```

**

Answer (score 0):

my problem got solved with these steps:

- booted into my USB device
- mounted my linux hardwares
- accessed the root
- created a file like this:

  nano /etc/sudoers
- added

  root ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
- and saved
- created another file:

  nano /etc/resolv.conf
- added:

  nameserver 8.8.8.8
- saved

it worked instantly

```
reboot

sudo -l
```

it gaves the following:
(ALL : ALL) ALL

my wifi settings were broken, so I used my USB Tethering from my mobile to update the wifi driver and the packages again.

my device is not using sudo anymore lol for some reason.
now, I can type any command without sudo

---

side notes:
I was chewing a gum when I started, my boss texted. a lot of pressure and I need to fix the project tomorrow morning.
I forgot the gum on my laptop, it got sticked to my sleeves, hard to get out.
I tried to sign up an account in this website, it refused cause apparently, I don't have cookies in my browser. oh.