# I accidentally did `sudo chmod -R g+w /.` 18.04

Tags: permissions, sudo

I CTRL+C after a few seconds but some harm was done already. E.g `sudo` command was giving an error when I tried to reuse it. Eventually I fixed it with this:

[Sudo comes up with an error, cannot run anything as root](https://askubuntu.com/questions/637432/sudo-comes-up-with-an-error-cannot-run-anything-as-root)

The question is, is my system doomed now? Will it just die next time it tries to update? Is it something that I can fix? Or should I pretend like nothing happened? I am afraid to reboot.

Comment: Systems are never doomed. We always have the live session as a fallback. `sudo chmod -R g+w ./` ... from where was it issued?  If you have sudo running again you can fix it all. Mind that all you did was add writeable to groups so that might not have been that harmful (at least you did not mess up the user permissions). And the only one that is frugal about alterations is the sudoers file.

Comment: It was issued from `~/my_folder`

Comment: Now that I think of it, it must have been `/.`, or else it doesn't make sense... Corrected the title.

Comment: @Rinzwind Unfortunately I was correct to think I've caused trouble. Disk space got exhausted due to `cups` error_log. Fixed with this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/836154/space-on-disk-running-low-error-logging-var-log-cups-error-log
Also wifi has stopped working altogether. I wonder what else is burning under the hood

Comment: @BillKotsias the /var/log directory has nowhere WRITE for group except for the "[bw]tmp.. Removing that will fix the log files.